# Graph showing data beyond a month

Tags: google-fit

I've activated Google Fit, so it monitors my daily activities. When I'm logged into my Google Account, visiting [fit.google.com](https://fit.google.com/) will give me all of the different activities. There's also the possibility to show a graphical presentation of the activities:

[image]

Is it possible to display a years time or since I've started?

Comment: How long have you using Google Fit? Do  you have recorded data for more than one year?

Comment: @ruben from october 2014 on. Bought a Sony smart Watch 3 3 months ago, to keep track of situps and pushups.....all with Android Wear 1.5....